# List contents of a directory via HTML/JavaScript on a local machine

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, directory

I'm making a "Jeopardy" board in HTML/JavaScript/XML. I want this app to be able to run on a local machine without having Apache or IIS installed. I figured we'd use a different XML file for each different round. So I figured I would need a way to specify which file to use. To do this, the most user-friendly way would be to list which XML files already exist in the directory, and list those in an HTML select-box, and let the user choose.

However, I'm stumped as to how to get the list of filenames in a specific directory. I could easily do it with PHP, but as I said before, I want it to work without Apache or IIS, and IE just plain sucks with their non-standards compliant BS, so I would really like not to be forced to use it for its FileObjectSystem ActiveX control.

Anyone know any other way of getting the folder contents into a JavaScript array?

Comment: @Tshepang: For future reference, it's probably not worth resurrecting a 4 year old question to just remove the signature at the end. Agreed it shouldn't be there, but I think the edit is a bit too minor.

Comment: I was also burninating [tag:contents]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a select-box, but the easiest way should be the use of a file-input. It allows the user to select a file from the local machine, and it allows your application to retrieve the path of the file that has been selected.

Assuming windows: FileSystemObject also works without IE, so if you use a jscript/vbscript for starting your application, you can first create a javascript-file containing an array with the available xml-files, and then run the application(document) with the default-browser.

Comment: Good one, I hadn't thought about using a "file" input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of would be to use [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/getting_started_air_js.html) or [Titanium Desktop](http://developer.appcelerator.com/documentation) for desktop File I/O with JavaScript using no server back-end.

Comment: I have no experience with those, but that would probably have been the better way to go. Perhaps I'll still look into them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I donno what is Jeopardy. However my 2 cents

If the XML content of the files is what you are really interested in you can define javascript variables to store XML and then use the XMLHttpRequest or ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") depending on the browser to parse and process the XML.

Comment: It's a trivia game show. Host asks questions, contenstants buzz in and answer. We would be reusing this application for many rounds of fun, so it wouldn't be a good idea to hardcode the questions and answers into the code. Not to mention, I'm one of the contestants, so our "host", who doesn't know anything about programming, will need to write the questions, so they need to be stored somewhere else than in the app code.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the directory listing output. I believe this varies by browser however and would be very difficult.

But if you request a url for a directory that does not have a landing page - at least locally you will get a list of files in that directory. If this works it would be a matter of parsing the page to find the file names.

Comment: I thought about this as well, but I realized that most of those directory listing pages are actually generated by Apache or IIS, so it wouldn't work when trying to get the directory listing on a local machine. When I tried it in IE, it just opened the folder in Windows Explorer, and when I tried it in FF, it did show a parseable string with the directory contents, but trying to get that string via Ajax led to a JavaScript error. Thanks anyways!